# ErrImagePull for custom Kafka Connect image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Trying to add more kafka connectors to our kafka cluster based on the following link's instructions . But getting failed with `errImagepull` error . Please find the details and help me resolve this .

Reference Link :

https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/extending.html#create-a-docker-image-containing-c-hub-connectors

Created Custom Docker Image  :

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-server-connect-operator:6.0.0.0
USER root
RUN   confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-tibco-source:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-azure-event-hubs:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-azure-event-hubs:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datadog-metrics:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-ftps:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-gcp-pubsub:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-gcs-source:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-pagerduty:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-sftp:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-teradata:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-tibco-source:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3-source:latest \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-gcs:latest
USER 1001
```

Push to publicaccess :

[image]

Updated in my-values.yaml

[image]

failing with errImagepull error :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

my-values.yaml

```
## Overriding values for Chart's values.yaml for AWS
##
global:
  provider:
    name: aws
    region: us-east-1
    ## Docker registry endpoint where Confluent Images are available.
    ##
    kubernetes:
     deployment:
      zones:
       - us-east-1a
       - us-east-1b
       - us-east-1c
    registry:
      fqdn: docker.io
      credential:
        required: false
  sasl:
    plain:
      username: test
      password: test123
  authorization:
    rbac:
      enabled: false
    simple:
      enabled: false
    superUsers: []
  dependencies:
    mds:
      endpoint: ""
      publicKey: ""
      
## Zookeeper cluster
##
zookeeper:
  name: zookeeper
  replicas: 3
  oneReplicaPerNode: true
  affinity:
   nodeAffinity:
     key: worker-type
     values: 
       - node-group-zookeeper
   rule: requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution    
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 200m
      memory: 512Mi

## Kafka Cluster
##
kafka:
  name: kafka
  replicas: 3
  oneReplicaPerNode: true
  affinity:
   nodeAffinity:
     key: worker-type
     values: 
       - node-group-broker
   rule: requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 200m
      memory: 1Gi
  loadBalancer:
    enabled: true
    type: internal
    domain: conf-ka01.dsol.core
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "0.0.0.0/0"
  tls:
    enabled: false
    fullchain: |-
    privkey: |-
    cacerts: |-
  metricReporter:
    enabled: true
    publishMs: 30000
    replicationFactor: ""
    tls:
     enabled: false
     internal: false
     authentication:
      type: ""
    bootstrapEndpoint: ""  

## Connect Cluster
##
connect:
  name: connectors
  image:
    repository: rdkarthikeyan27/hebdevkafkaconnectors
    tag: 1.0
  oneReplicaPerNode: false
  affinity:
   nodeAffinity:
     key: worker-type
     values: 
       - node-group-connector
   rule: requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution      
  replicas: 2
  tls:
    enabled: false
    ## "" for none, "tls" for mutual auth
    authentication:
      type: ""
    fullchain: |-
    privkey: |-
    cacerts: |-
  loadBalancer:
    enabled: true
    type: internal
    domain: conf-ka01.dsol.core
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "0.0.0.0/0"
  dependencies:
    kafka:
      bootstrapEndpoint: kafka:9071
      brokerCount: 3
    schemaRegistry:
      enabled: true
      url: http://schemaregistry:8081
## Replicator Connect Cluster
##
replicator:
  name: replicator
  oneReplicaPerNode: false
  replicas: 0
  tls:
    enabled: false
    authentication:
      type: ""
    fullchain: |-
    privkey: |-
    cacerts: |-
  loadBalancer:
    enabled: true
    type: internal
    domain: conf-ka01.dsol.core
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "0.0.0.0/0"
  dependencies:
    kafka:
      brokerCount: 3
      bootstrapEndpoint: kafka:9071
##
## Schema Registry
##
schemaregistry:
  name: schemaregistry
  oneReplicaPerNode: false
  affinity:
   nodeAffinity:
     key: worker-type
     values: 
       - node-group-schema-reg 
   rule: requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution
  tls:
    enabled: false
    authentication:
      type: ""
    fullchain: |-
    privkey: |-
    cacerts: |-
  loadBalancer:
    enabled: true
    type: internal
    domain: conf-ka01.dsol.core
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "0.0.0.0/0"
  dependencies:
    kafka:
      brokerCount: 3
      bootstrapEndpoint: kafka:9071

##
## KSQL
##
ksql:
  name: ksql
  replicas: 2
  oneReplicaPerNode: true
  affinity:
   nodeAffinity:
     key: worker-type
     values: 
       - node-group-ksql
   rule: requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution    
  tls:
    enabled: false
    authentication:
      type: ""
    fullchain: |-
    privkey: |-
    cacerts: |-
  loadBalancer:
    enabled: true
    type: internal
    domain: conf-ka01.dsol.core
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "0.0.0.0/0"
  dependencies:
    kafka:
      brokerCount: 3
      bootstrapEndpoint: kafka:9071
      brokerEndpoints: kafka-0.kafka:9071,kafka-1.kafka:9071,kafka-2.kafka:9071
    schemaRegistry:
      enabled: false
      tls:
        enabled: false
        authentication:
          type: ""
      url: http://schemaregistry:8081

## Control Center (C3) Resource configuration
##
controlcenter:
  name: controlcenter
  license: ""
  ##
  ## C3 dependencies
  ##
  dependencies:
    c3KafkaCluster:
      brokerCount: 3
      bootstrapEndpoint: kafka:9071
      zookeeper:
        endpoint: zookeeper:2181
    connectCluster:
      enabled: true
      url: http://connectors:8083
    ksql:
      enabled: true
      url: http://ksql:9088
    schemaRegistry:
      enabled: true
      url: http://schemaregistry:8081
  oneReplicaPerNode: false
  affinity:
   nodeAffinity:
     key: worker-type
     values: 
       - node-group-control
   rule: requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution
  ##
  ## C3 External Access
  ##
  loadBalancer:
    enabled: true
    type: internal
    domain: conf-ka01.dsol.core
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "0.0.0.0/0"
  ##
  ## TLS configuration
  ##
  tls:
    enabled: false
    authentication:
      type: ""
    fullchain: |-
    privkey: |-
    cacerts: |-
  ##
  ## C3 authentication
  ##
  auth:
    basic:
      enabled: true
      ##
      ## map with key as user and value as password and role
      property:
        admin: Developer1,Administrators
        disallowed: no_access
```

Comment: Please show `kubectl describe pod connectors-1`

Comment: Please find the details . bash-3.2$ kubectl logs connectors-1
Error from server (BadRequest): container "connectors" in pod "connectors-1" is waiting to start: image can't be pulled

Comment: And what about `kubectl describe` that I asked for?

Comment: I have edited with kubectl describe pod connectors-1 details

Comment: Well, where in your values are you setting a tag of `1.0.0`? In your shown values, you only have `1.0`, which appears unused... That would also explain why the image name is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Image from docker io https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-server-connect-operator doesn’t have tag 1.0.0 available . Try tag 6.0.0.0
That is confluentinc/cp-server-connect-operator:6.0.0.0

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here am trying to use my custom docker image . not with confluentinc . https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/rdkarthikeyan27/hebdevkafkaconnectors

Comment: @KarthikeyanRasipalayDurairaj if you look at ur last image https://i.stack.imgur.com/63iBI.png, its complaining about the image from docker hub

Comment: got it . In that case ,How can i use my custom image in my-values.yaml . please suggest

Comment: Somehow u have configured wrong image , take a look at https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bnRH.png it says ur image name is wrong

Comment: @KarthikeyanRasipalayDurairaj did u manage to fix it?

Comment: No . I have mentioned the custom image details  myvalues.yaml as like  image: 
    respository: rdkarthikeyan27/dsol-connectors
    tag: 1.0  but not taking the right image

Comment: @KarthikeyanRasipalayDurairaj can u share ur yaml please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225381/discussion-between-karthikeyan-rasipalay-durairaj-and-abhijit-gaikwad).